# ¿Porque al abrir el Modal se queda con la clase modal-backdrop fade in?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Tengo un botón que al hacer click se debería abrir un modal, pero se queda con la clase modal-backdrop fade in y no aparece el modal (tampoco puedo cerrarlo).

El codigo es este:

```
<td class="orderproject tdcenter"><p id="margindata">{{$project->order}}</p>
                      <div class="editdeleteproyecto editdeleteproyectoinsideorden">
                          <a href="{{ route('admin.project.edit', $project->id)}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm editmenuproject" id="margindata">Edit</a> 
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deletemenuproject" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formdeleteproject_{{$project->id}}" id="margindata">Delete</button>

                          <div id="formdeleteproject_{{$project->id}}" class="modal fade" role="dialog"> <!-- DIV TO SHOW THE CREATE PROJECT FORM 1 START HERE-->
                             <div class="modal-dialog" style="background-color:#23517F;">
                             <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:#23517F;">
                             <div class="modal-header">
                               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                               <h4 class="modal-title" style="color:black;">¿Estas seguro de borrar el proyecto?</h4>
                             </div>
                             <div class="modal-body">
                              <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <a href="{{ route('admin.projects') }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-block colsm6btnno">No</a>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-sm-6">
                               <form method="POST" action="{{route('admin.projects.destroy',$project->id)}}">
                                <input type="submit" value="Si" class="btn btn-danger btn-block colsm6btnsi">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{Session::token()}}">
                                {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                               </form>
                              </div>
                             </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="closemodal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                         </div>
                         </div>
                         </div>
                      </div>
</td>
```

La pantalla se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Trata de armar un fiddle con tu código (añadiendo los scripts  y estilos) para poder recrear el problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca el código del cuadro modal `<div id="formdeleteproject_{{$project->id}}" class="modal fade" role="dialog">...</div>` **fuera** de la tabla (en el código lo tienes dentro de un `<td>`).

La [documentación de Boostrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals) dice que coloques el HTML del modal en el nivel más alto del documento que sea posible (o sea, lo más cerca de `<body>`) para no afectar la apariencia o funcionalidad.

> **Modal markup placement**. Always try to place a modal's HTML code in a top-level position in your document to avoid other components affecting the modal's appearance and/or functionality.